# Как отменить правила псевдоэлементов :before и :after

Tags: css

Eсть секция хочу отменить( вернее даже скрыть) при уменьшении  экрана правила псевдоэлементов :before и :after

```css
  .otz {
  background-color: #e7efff;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    top: -18px;
    background: url("images/otz_top.png") center bottom no-repeat;
  }
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    bottom: -25px;
    background: url("images/otz_bottom.png") center bottom no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

Будет правильно написать псевдоелементу display: none; ?

Comment: можно сделать width: 0

Comment: А что не так с display: none?

Comment: да хотел хотел узнать какие варианты есть в такой ситуации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

использовать @media с указанием max-width

```
.otz {

  ...

  @media(max-width: 760px){
    &::before, &::after{
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно выполнить отмену через JS:

```
client_w=document.body.clientWidth;
if(client_w<"???px"){
document.getElementById("???").classList.remove("&::before");
document.getElementById("???").classList.remove("&::after");
}
if(client_w>"???px"){
document.getElementById("???").classList.add("&::before");
document.getElementById("???").classList.add("&::after");
}
```

или просто убрать:

```
client_w=document.body.clientWidth;
    if(client_w<"???px"){
    document.getElementById("???").style.display="none";
    }
    if(client_w>"???px"){
    document.getElementById("???").style.display="block";
    }
```